# Create objct of certain type, which returns true for instanceof, without using new

Tags: typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, instanceof

I'm currently writing unit tests and one part of the logic, is checking if and input element is of a certain type. Since I'm using angular, I cannot create this object without a serious overhead. (The object in question is a MatSelect).

Now I wanted to know if there is way, to just define a object and create/cast and object to this specific tpye, without using `new`?

This is the constructor of the object I want to create:

```
export declare class MatSelect ...     
constructor(_viewportRuler: ViewportRuler, _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, _ngZone: NgZone, _defaultErrorStateMatcher: ErrorStateMatcher, elementRef: ElementRef, _dir: Directionality, _parentForm: NgForm, _parentFormGroup: FormGroupDirective, _parentFormField: MatFormField, ngControl: NgControl, tabIndex: string, scrollStrategyFactory: any, _liveAnnouncer: LiveAnnouncer);
```

this is what I tired so far:

```
const dummy = <MatSelect><unknown> {};
const dummy2 = {} as MatSelect;
```

both didn't satisfy the `instanceof` check

Comment: Well this is how [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) work in javascript. Typescript's type assertions (`as` or `<>`) erased at compile time and have no effect at runtime

Answer (score 0):

`instanceof` will check for the actual prototype of `MatSelect`, so you won't be able to get it to return true without actually using the actual MatSelect class (or a subclass).
Since you're using Angular, you might want to provide a fake MatSelect component in your TestBed.

Comment: Do you know an easy way to do this. Because as I said, I want to avoid this since it produces a lot of overhead. Also Angulars unit tests for MatSelect, don't really help (see: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/select/select.spec.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer: [Reimplemented Constructor[Symbol.hasInstance] but it still won't be called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982924/reimplemented-constructorsymbol-hasinstance-but-it-still-wont-be-called)

I found my the following workaround:

```
it('testdummy', () => {
    // allows us tho define any object as MatSelect without the overhead of TestBed.createComponent
    // based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/40983417
    Object.defineProperty(MatSelect, Symbol.hasInstance, {
      value: function (instance) {
        return instance.isMatSelect;
      }
    });

    const directive = new SomeDirective(
      <MatFormField><unknown>{
        _elementRef: {nativeElement: 'test'},
        _control: {isMatSelect: true, openedChange: EMPTY}
    }, ...
```

When it is defined like this `_control instanceof MatSelect` returns `true`!